# How to change Bitmap'sColor Temperature using ColorMatrix?

Tags: android, matrix, colors, bitmap, colormatrix

How can i change color temperature of a bitmap ?

I tried this method i've found on the net:

```
 ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();

 colorMatrix.set(new float[] {
            temp/255.0f, 0, 0, 0, 0,
             0, temp/255.0f, 0, 0, 0
             0, 0, temp/255.0f, 0, 0,
             0, 0, 0, 1, 0}); 
// temp is the float i change with seekbar's progress
//i replace 255.0f with values from below's link!
```

http://www.vendian.org/mncharity/dir3/blackbody/UnstableURLs/bbr_color.html

Comment: hth http://blog.gskinner.com/archives/2007/12/colormatrix_cla.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you sure you are not talking about ColorFilter?

```
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bmp);
drawable.setColorFilter(warmColor, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Comment: thanks a lot for support, i just resolved now with color matrix, i finally found what values i should change and its working

Comment: @BlerimBlerii can you share the values you used to resolve your problem? I have the same issue